# How much does the $L^p$ norms say about a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let's say we have two positive, decreasing function $u$ and $v$ on $[0,+\infty)$, and we know that $\|u\|_{L^p}=\|v\|_{L^p}$ for all $p\ge1$, can we say something about $u$ and $v$? Do they have to be the same function?

Comment: with "decreasing" we can't say $u(x) = v(x+1)$ anymore. it also proves that $u(0) = v(0)$ (supposing $\|u\|_{\infty}$ exists)

Comment: I think by making the domain one-sided (so that you cannot simply take translates), assuming monotonicity (so that you cannot somehow "compose with a permutation"), and assuming positivity (so that you cannot simply alter signs), you actually do get that they are identical. I'm not sure how to prove it. Must you have $u(0)$ and $v(0)$ finite?

Comment: @user1952009 No idea what you mean, I was basically saying "you seem to have made the right assumptions to rule out all the obvious counterexamples".

Comment: @Ian : ok so you had to write this :) and what if $u$ and $v$ are $C^\infty$ ? can we prove $u = v$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check all details, but you can try this: For the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,\infty)$ an application of Fubini's theorem gives,for $p>1$,
$\|u\|_{L^p}^p=p \int\limits_0^\infty x^{p-1} \lambda(\lbrace u>x\rbrace)dx$. Then approximate  $f(x)= \lambda(\lbrace u>x\rbrace)- \lambda(\lbrace v>x\rbrace)$ by ploynomials to get $\int_0^\infty|f(x)|dx=0$ and hence $f=0$ by continuity. From $\lambda(\lbrace u>x\rbrace)= \lambda(\lbrace v>x\rbrace)$, continuity, and the monotonicity of $u,v$ it should follow that $u=v$.

Comment: I think the factor is $p$ and not $p-1$. And the formula does work for $p=1$.

Comment: You're right. After the edit the formula also works for $p=1$.